# react-native init (0.57) Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-external-helpers'

Tags: react-native

When I create a brand new react native project, I get this error message:

> Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-external-helpers'

My **package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "TestProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "0.57.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.45.4",    
    "react-test-renderer": "16.5.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

Same thing for me, just  run

npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-external-helpers

and it should works

Comment: in addition to the instruction above, also remove the build folder and restart the packager.

Answer (score 1):

just install @babel/plugin-external-helpers, no need to change .babelrc
For me, fixed this issue by installing @babel/plugin-external-helpers and react-transform-hmr.

Run:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-external-helpers
npm install react-transform-hmr
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just resolved it by installing Babel from here:
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-external-helpers

Comment: Can you please make it more clear, I just try `npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-external-helpers` but not works

Comment: I tried `npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-external-helpers` as well and even edited my .babelrc file to add `"plugins": ["@babel/plugin-external-helpers"]` and I still get that same error

Comment: @LuongTruong I was working in android project, install from the link I shared above, then run-android and it just working with no error at all.

Comment: @ramose: Thank you for replying, I try but fail. I don't know why but after I restart my computer, the project works again.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers probably work if you didn't update XCode.  Upgrading react-native, XCode, and my iOS all in the span of a couple days completely broke everything.

Starting a new project to test with react-native 0.57, I encountered the same problem you did, and installed the package, however that did not solve the problem.  I'd seen another post talking about the build system change in XCode 10, so I tried that and this worked for me:

1. `npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-external-helpers` as mentioned
2. Open the project in XCode
3. Go to `File > Project Settings`
4. Change `Build System` to `Legacy Build System`

Comment: Anyone know why step 1 is now needed?

Answer (score 0):

We got same error here! We can't run any react native project (both iOS and Android). Those projects use react-native version 0.56.0.

If we create a project with react-native version 0.42.0 it works: `react-native init [project_name] --version 0.42.0`

Although using `npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-external-helpers` does not work for us. Neither using `npm install react-transform-hmr`.

Answer (score 0):

Using yarn, just running:

```
yarn add --dev @babel/plugin-external-helpers
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this. It is a known issue and we are working on it.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21219

Answer (score 0):

Just installed a new project and it seems fixed.

New version of the metro-react-native-babel-preset package.

Below the package.json file I get after a fresh install.

> "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.45.5"

```
{
  "name": "ZStyleCachedImage",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "0.57.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.45.5",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.5.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```